# Unable to format internal disk: disk is read-only

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, apfs, formatting

I'm having a strange issue with my MacBook Pro (13" early 2015 running macOS Catalina 10.15.7): few days ago I was using my computer when it has suddenly shut down, when i powered it back on and provided my password it has shut down again and it keeps doing this every time I try to log into the system, plus, it seems that the safe mode is unavailable.
I'd like to format the internal SSD drive (currently formatted as APFS encrypted with FileVault enabled) and proceed with a clean install of the OS but as I can see the internal disk is in read-only mode and when I try to format it from recovery I get permission denied.
I also tried to boot from a bootable USB drive having Big Sur on it but I'm unable to format the drive nor install the OS. I tried running the built-in diagnostic routine but no disk issue was found.
I finally tried to remove the SSD drive and put it on a Thunderbolt case in order to format it from another Mac but I get a similar error even if the "Ignore ownership on this volume" option is ticked.
I managed to copy some of my data from the internal drive to an external one using the terminal in recovery mode, now I would like to wipe out all the contents from my internal drive and install a fresh copy of macOS (Catalina or Big Sur), how can I format a SSD drive in this condition?

I described this issue on Reddit too and I added a link to another Reddit post where I listed some other software related issue I had and I though they were related to the disk or the filesystem, maybe this may be helpful. https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/kpafn0/unable_to_format_internal_disk_disk_is_readonly/

Comment: I boot the system from a **Linux Live OS USB**  flash drive and see if you can format/wipe the **SSD** from there, and then boot from a **macOS USB Installer** and see if you can install it then.

Comment: @user3439894 I tried to boot from Ubuntu 20.04.1 on an USB drive then I tried formatting the internal drive using GParted but I got an input/output error, so I guess even Linux can't format this disk.